# Jquery table with array of data/ grouping of data

Tags: jquery, tabular

I want to display a table of data but with hierarchy as shown in the below image:

[image]

I have searched a lot of jQuery table but none seems to be having this type of table.

Is there any jQuery/Javascript table by which I can accomplish this?

Anyone?

Comment: k.. level, average for section target score where it comes from? can u show json result output?

Comment: Average we are calculating from level/number of level. Target score we are getting from json. I can submit the json output but it will not print here in correct format.

Comment: Just looks like a `table` - what is jQuery about this?

Comment: you are right. This table is not build using jquery but I was thinking if there is a jquery plugin by which we can do this easily?

Comment: found the answer here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-table-for-reporting